# Raycast2D not working as intended

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am doing a mario prototype and (in this context) i am using two Raycasts, one pointing from mario up to the top of his head. That is used when mario is touching the blocks in the air. The second raycast is used down to the bottom of the feet to detect when he is stepping on a Goomba (enemy). I have included a function down below which shows that i use the same structure on both of the rays and "if" statements, but despite that, only the first one (on head) works.

```
public void marioRaycast()
{
    RaycastHit2D hitUp = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, new Vector2(0, 1), hitUpDistance); // Raycast som pekar upp, +1
    RaycastHit2D hitDown = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, new Vector2(0, -1), hitDownDistance); // Raycast som pekar ner, -1

    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, new Vector2(0, hitUpDistance), Color.green); // Visualiserar en "raycaststråle" för att debugga.
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, new Vector2(0, hitDownDistance), Color.green); // Visualiserar en "raycaststråle" för att debugga.

    if (hitUp && hitUp.collider.tag == "CoinBox")
    {
        questionObject = hitUp.collider.gameObject;
        if (questionObject.GetComponent<QuestionmarkBox>().coinBoxStatus)
        {
            if (questionObject.GetComponent<QuestionmarkBox>().getRandomNr() <= 4) // "40%" för poäng ifrån box
            {
                ScoreHandler.AddScore(100);
            }

            else // Låg chans för powerup.
            {
                questionObject.GetComponent<QuestionmarkBox>().instantiatePowerUp();
            }
        }
        questionObject.GetComponent<QuestionmarkBox>().coinBoxStatus = false; // Stänger av blockets relevans efter kollision
    }


    if (hitDown && hitDown.collider.tag == "enemyGoomba")
    {
        Debug.Log("You are now in the goomba if");
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * 100);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.right * 200);
        Destroy(hitDown.collider.gameObject); // Förstör goomban.
    }


}
```

If you need more information on the script tell me. And in the last "if" statement it has not reached the "Debug.Log" yet, which is my goal. It doesn't seem listen to either the last statement or maybe the ray / possibly enemy?

I dont see how the 2nd ray is not working just because of the earlier ray working when theres no difference to them both, except some "values". What could it be?

Comment: Are both rays drawing correctly? What is your value for hitdowndistance? is it negative? if it is, you are casting a negative ray in the downwards direction - which is up.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but i've already tried changing the values on hitdownDistance. When its -0.7f its a bit under his feet, so i tried 0.7f before and it still didnt work. I even tried with numbers like -5 and +5 so i have no idea :(

Comment: To be consistent, I would have the direction for the vector in hitDown be Vector2(0,1) and use a negative value for hitdownDistance. Right now you are doing DrawRay in the opposite direction that it is being cast. I don't see any problems with your code otherwise, it could be a tagging issue or there is something incorrect with how your objects are set up.

Comment: I think -1 is fine, because with 1 it will point up like the first. I agree though that i am pointing the DrawRay wrong, but that is only debugging and it should work. And i actually only did the debug.ray like that because my parameters in my rays have a variable called "distance" and the debug didnt have that, so i had to place the distance in the "direction" if that makes sense. But ye, i have no idea what it could be, i suppose its something small i cant see with my eyes..

Comment: The strange part is, i commented away this: `RaycastHit2D hitDown = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, hitDownDistance);` To replace it with this one: `RaycastHit2D hitUpv2 = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up, hitUpDistance);` And it works, but this is just a copy of my 1s array. I touched the enemy with marios head and it worked. It must be some value? Though i have tried with different values as i said in both the direction and distance parameters. So for example -1, +1 in direction, and -0.7f, 0.7f, 3f, -3f, so i actually have no idea what it could be.....

Comment: Ray casts that originate inside a collider don’t hit that collider. Perhaps your origin point of the raycast is already inside the Goomba?