# Raycast2d not working with compareTag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I ran into a little problem with a enemy AI script of mine where the raycast doesn't want to work with me. The code is as follows:

```
void DetectionF(float distanceToTarget)
{
float angle = Vector2.Angle(vision, target.position);
if (lastAngle!=angle)
    Debug.Log("Angle: " + angle);
lastAngle = angle;


Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, target.position, Color.red, 0.2f);
if (70f< angle && angle<140f)
{
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, target.position, distanceToTarget);
    //This right here is where the problem lays
    if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        player.detected = true;
        CancelInvoke("Undetect");
    }
}
}
```

I simply need to confirm that the raycast hit the player and nothing else.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code. Verify that your player is tagged correctly and that the ray is being cast correctly. Perhaps try using Debug.DrawRay to make sure.

Comment: @ryeMoss I did the drawRay with the same settings as the raycast and it Points in another direction than the drawLine but even when both come in contact with the player (that is tagged correctly btw) nothing happens.

Comment: Is `distanceToTarget` a negative value? I'm just fishing for a solution at this point since everything seems fine but I've run across a problem with a negative ray before.

Comment: here is the example I was referring to. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47582895/raycast2d-not-working-as-intended#comment82124761_47582895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure that the gameObject that the ray is hitting, is truly tagged as "Player". If it is, then what I believe to be the best way to deal with this problem is by trying to make 2 seperate if() statements in order to achieve what you want.
For example:

```
if(hit.collider.gameObject){
        if(gameObject.tag == "Player"){
            player.detected = true;
            CancelInvoke("Undetect");
    }
}
```

Hopefully this solves your problem!